# With the suddenness of night-time eruption in a chicken-coop

Tags: meaning-in-context

I didn't understand the meaning of this sentence -

> Then, with the suddenness of night-time eruption in a chicken-coop, a group of women burst out of the fort.

I guess **night-time eruption** means **the fall of night**. But what it has to do with **chicken-coop**, when there is no mention or occurrence of such thing in the context?

Answer (score 4):

This sentence contains two parts. One part literal description, one part figurative speech. 
So let's dissect this:

1. Plain text:

> Then,[...], a group of women burst out of the fort.
>   
>   -> Take this literally: Some women leaving a place in a hasty manner.

2. Figurative text:

> ...with the suddenness of night-time eruption in a chicken-coop...
>   
>   -> Consider this image (that describes the behaviour of the women): 
> Chicken, asleep in their coop. A fox sneaks inside. Suddenly, all hens wake up and start screetching and flapping. General mayhem ensues. -> There you have your "night-time eruption in the chicken-coop".

Comment: Very nice imagery in your description. Also, it might be worth explicitly explaining that "night-time" describes the time that the eruption of noise and mayhem occurred because it seems to be a point of confusion in the original question.